# Multiple image upload and preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image-upload

I am learning how to upload multiple images and showing their preview...

I came across the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.input-file-row-1:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.input-file-row-1{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 25px;
position: relative;
}

#preview_image {
display: none;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
margin: 2px 0px 0px 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.upload-file-container { 
position: relative; 
width: 100px; 
height: 137px; 
overflow: hidden;   
background: url('images/picplus.png') top center no-repeat;
float: left;
margin-left: 23px;
} 

.upload-file-container-text{
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #719d2b;
line-height: 17px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
width: 100px; 
height: 35px;
}

.upload-file-container-text > span{
border-bottom: 1px solid #719d2b;
cursor: pointer;
}

.one_opacity_0 {
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
width: 1px;
float: left;
}
</style>
<script>
function readURL(input,target)
{
if(input.files && input.files[0])
{
var reader=new FileReader();
var image_target=$(target);
reader.onload=function(e)
{
    image_target.attr('src',e.target.result).show();
};
reader.readAsDataUrl(input.files[0]);
}
}

$("patient_pic").live("change",function(){
readURL(this,"#preview_image")
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" class="feedback-form-1">
<fieldset>
    <div class="input-file-row-1">
        <div class="upload-file-container">
            <img id="preview_image" src="#" alt="" />
            <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                    <input type="file" id="patient_pic" label = "add" />
                </div>
                <span> Add Photo </span>
            </div>

<div class="upload-file-container-text">
                <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                    <input type="file" id="patient_pic" label = "add" />
                </div>
                <span> Add Photo </span>
            </div>
    
</div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I came across this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dn9Sr/2/) which explains it perfectly to me. But being a beginner I know it includes a jQuery library which clearly shows in framework extension of Fiddle. Now my issue is, how should I include it when I start the coding on my machine?

What will be included in the head (`<script src="???">`) section to make a call to the library?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Below is a working example of a solution to preview multiple uploaded image. ([Source](https://maraustria.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/multiple-select-and-preview-of-image-of-file-upload/), [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/))

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Check File API support
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        //Only pics
        if (!file.type.match('image'))
          continue;
        var picReader = new FileReader();
        picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
          var picFile = event.target;
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
          output.insertBefore(div, null);
        });
        //Read the image
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: ‘Segoe UI’;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1BA1E2;
  padding: 20px;
}

article {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id='post-form' class='post-form' method='post'>
  <label for='files'>Select multiple files: </label>
  <input id='files' type='file' multiple/>
  <output id='result' />
</form>
```

Comment: https://maraustria.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/multiple-select-and-preview-of-image-of-file-upload/

Comment: the images being uploaded are shown in vertical alignment... how to show them horizontally.. like one after another not one below other

Comment: .thumbnail{
float:left;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
}

Comment: this is a wonderful solution.. thank you.. i hope it will work great if i integrate it with php... thanks a ton again

Comment: was wondering that how can i will be displaying name of the selected file below each thumbnail. can you help

Comment: in js replace the

 div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "‘" +
"title='" + picFile.name + "‘/>"; 

to

 div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
"title='" + file.name + "'/>" + "<span>" + file.name +"<span>";

that's it.

Comment: file name are appearing in fiddle... but they aint exactly below it.. they are appearing at bottom right

Comment: I updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/28/
or
https://maraustria.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/multiple-select-and-preview-of-image-of-file-upload/

Answer (score 1):

First include Jquery library in your `<head>` section

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then below that

```
<script>
$(function(){

//Here your function

});
</script>
```

Change in your function use `on` instead of `live`

```
$("patient_pic").on("change",function(){
readURL(this,"#preview_image")
});
```

jQuery has deprecated `live()` since 1.7, instead use `on()`

Comment: Thank you for reply i did it but still image previews are not displayed

Comment: any ideas why preview is not being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

//Your Code Goes Here

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Your H
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you... any idea why the images are not being previewed after uploading them??

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? Are you talking about multiple Image Preview not happening in the Fiddle?

Comment: i copied the code in notepad and saved it with .html extension... it shows the output with plus symbol.. but wheni actually upload an image.. it doesn't shows the preview

Comment: You want the Code implementation in a single file?

Comment: no not needed.. have decided to seperate the css in css named folder

Comment: when i actually do this.. it doesnt shows the preview of image

Comment: hei there.. now the things are working up.. but as i try to preview multiple images.. i get preview at only first section... here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arpymastro/SFHF6/

Comment: I suppose you already got the correct answer form the first answer... since it is marked correct right?

Comment: yes it did resolved my first issue... but now another issue is.. wheni try multiple uploading of images.. only one get previewed.. here is the fiddle- jsfiddle.net/arpymastro/SFHF6