# Multiple image in one button with preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

i have a little problem with image upload preview. Here's the preview of the element :

[image: image element]

And this is the code :

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="preview-1" src="" alt="" />
  <div class="more">
    <img id="preview-2" src="" alt="" />
    <img id="preview-3" src="" alt="" />
    <span>Max 3 images.</span>
  </div>
  <label for="upload-btn" class="button">
    <img src="ssts/img/svg/upload.svg" alt="" />
    <span>UPLOAD</span>
    <input id="upload-btn" name="upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
  </label>
</div>
```

My problem is, how do i upload more than one image in single button and it will automatically show the preview in the element ? And after all of the element filled, the `upload button` will change to "Remove" that if clicked it will remove all the preview ? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

the most important question is, "showing all of choosen images, and automatically show to the preview"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file

Comment: Do the preview and the remove ... I guess is a little complex process , have you searched/try anything ?

Comment: You might be interested in [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: google is your friend you just need to filter each step you want ... don't expect to find all the code for that you want

Comment: i know multiple will select more than one image, but what i need is when i select all the images i want to uploaded it will automatically show to the preview @DaniP

Comment: just search check the second question I linked on the comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple image upload and preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779983/multiple-image-upload-and-preview) check first answer of this question

Comment: Or duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683579/how-to-provide-a-preview-for-multiple-images-selected-in-fileuplaod-using-jquery

Comment: @DaniP here's the example, i have 3 images. First image will showing in the biggest one preview, second and third image will show in `more` element. In that question just showing all of selected image without `class`.

Comment: then just adjust that code to your needs ... try something

Comment: @DaniP that's what i don't understand about..

Comment: @Badacadabra i know this, another question has been answered and all of this comment things that i need `multiple` and mark this as duplicate, but this is totally different with the others.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific on your question ... as I said again those linked questions had the answer play with the styles chekc this updated http://jsfiddle.net/Yvgc2/1545/

Comment: @DaniP Thanks for keep answering my question, but that answer you linked to is just uploading image with the same `class` named `thumbnail` each image. What i need is different with that. The first one will show in the biggest one and the others will show in `more` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/multiple) attribute and you need to specify that the `name` is an array.

> ### multiple (HTML5)
>
> This Boolean attribute indicates whether the user can enter more than one value. This attribute applies when the type attribute is set to email or file, otherwise it is ignored.

```
<input id="upload-btn" name="upload[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
```

You can find a example using PHP here:

> [How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

The following demo was adapted from this:

> [Multiple image upload and preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295815/1762224)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Check for File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById('upload-btn');
    filesInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var output = document.getElementById('result');
      var files = e.target.files; //FileList object
      
      output.innerHTML = ''; // Clear (previous) results.
      
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currFile = files[i];
        if (!currFile.type.match('image')) continue; // Skip non-images.
        
        var imgReader = new FileReader();
        imgReader.fileName = currFile.name;
        imgReader.addEventListener('load', function(e1) {
          var img = e1.target;
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.className = 'thumbnail';
          div.innerHTML = [
            '<img src="' + img.result + '"' + 'title="' + img.fileName + '"/>',
            '<label class="caption">' + img.fileName + '</label>'
          ].join('');
          output.appendChild(div);
        });

        // Read image.
        imgReader.readAsDataURL(currFile);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Your browser does not support File API!');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 0.125em;
}
article {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
output {
  display: block;
}
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}
.thumbnail img {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
label.caption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>File API - FileReader</h1>
</header>
<article>
  <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
  <input type="file" id="upload-btn" name="upload[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
  <output id="result" />
</article>
```

```js
const IMAGE_LIMIT = 3;
window.onload = function() {
  // Check for File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById('upload-btn');
    filesInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var output = document.getElementById('result');
      var files = e.target.files; //FileList object
      
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var currFile = files[i];
        if (!currFile.type.match('image')) continue; // Skip non-images.
        
        var imgReader = new FileReader();
        imgReader.fileName = currFile.name;
        imgReader.index = i;
        imgReader.addEventListener('load', function(e1) {
          var img = e1.target;
          var index = img.index;
          if (index < IMAGE_LIMIT) {
            var imgContainer = document.getElementById('preview-' + (index + 1));
            imgContainer.src = img.result;
            imgContainer.title = img.fileName
          }
        });

        // Read image.
        imgReader.readAsDataURL(currFile);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Your browser does not support File API!');
  }
}
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #DADFE2; }
.img-container {
  width: 284px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
img[id^="preview-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: border: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 0.25em;
  background: #DADFE2;
}
#preview-1 {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
#preview-2, #preview-3 {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #FF6B6F;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 98%;
  text-align: center;
}
.button:hover { cursor: pointer; background: #ff8486; }
.button:active { background: #e55052; }
input[type="file"]#upload-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="preview-1" src="" alt="" />
  <div class="more">
    <img id="preview-2" src="" alt="" />
    <img id="preview-3" src="" alt="" />
    <span>Max 3 images.</span>
  </div>
  <label for="upload-btn" class="button">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" id="upload-btn" name="upload[]"  accept="image/*" multiple />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: And how to preview all of those images automatically ?

Comment: here's the example, i have 3 images. First image will showing in the biggest one preview, second and third image will show in `more` element. In that question just showing all of selected image without `class`

Comment: @GilangRizkie I have added an example.

Comment: How do i make the 1st image it showed in `preview-1` ? 2nd image in `preview-2` ? 3rd image in `preview-3` ? Your example only show in same `id`, i have its own `class` for the images. Thanks.

Comment: @GilangRizkie In the `imgReader.addEventListener('load')` function, just grab the current index (`i`) and set the appropriate image values instead of writing out to the results.

Comment: so it will look like `imgReader.addEventListener('load[1]')` for showing the 1st one image ? and the rest will use default `imgReader.addEventListener('load')` without index inserted ?

Comment: @GilangRizkie OK, added a second example, it is hidden by default. Click it to expand.

Comment: THANKS SIR, U SAVE MY DAY! ITS SOLVED!!

Comment: And last sir, if its add more that 3 images which images will stored to database if submitted ?

Comment: @GilangRizkie You have all the images here... `e.target.files` Just store their base64 data. But it is more proper to save the files to the server and save their file location to a database. Images take up too much space.